# How to take out subscription list in Larvel?

Tags: laravel

I'm creating project with Laravel. I want to pull out `user->name` from subscription table which also has `user_id` column in it. I want to show the current user's subscribers' name from subscription table. But it shows error:

```
Property [subs] does not exist on this collection instance
```

here is my code.

This is from IndexController

```
public function home() {
    $data = User::all();
    return view("amvs.index", [
        'users' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

This is from index.blade.php

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border rounded-0">Subscriptions</a>
@foreach ($users->subs as $sub)
    <span class="ms-2">{{$subs->name}}</span>
@endforeach
```

This is from user model

```
public function sub(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Subscription');
}
```

I didn't write anything in Subscription model. My subscription table

```
Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My user table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I'm a beginner so enlighten me.

Comment: `@foreach ($users->sub as $sub)<span class="ms-2">{{$sub->name}}</span>@endforeach`

Comment: That's the same as my code. Isn't it? That'll make a different?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto `$users` is an [Eloquent Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-collections) which doesn't have a `sub` property so your code will still throw an error.

Comment: Don't you see the difference?

Comment: @Peppermintology please answer this question. I know you get the point.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto Adding `()` to `sub` will not work either as `$users` is a collection not an instance of `User` which is where the relationship is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to access a method on an [Eloquent Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-collections) which does not have any properties or methods relatated to your `User` or its `sub` relationship.

Additionally, consider using [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) when accessing relationships, it is more performant and solves the `N+1` query problem.

```
public function home() {
    // access the authenticated User and load their subs relationship
    $user = Auth::user()->with('subs')->first();

    return view("amvs.index", [
        'user' => $user
    ]);
}
```

Then to access the `User`s subs in your view:

```
@foreach ($user->subs as $sub)
{
    <span class="ms-2">{{$sub->name}}</span>
}
```

However, you will want to change your `subscriptions` migration as the `user_id` field needs to be the same `type` as the `id` field on your `users` table.

```
Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->foreignId('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Further questions**

> don't know why I should use foreignId?

For relationships to work, the field `type` (`string`, `integer` etc.) of the `primary` and `foreign` key fieds **must** be the same. The default primary key in Laravel is the `id` field and it has as `type` of `unsigned big integer`. If you define a `foreign` key field in a related table and its `type` is anything other than `unsignedBigInteger` the relationship will fail.

`foreignId` is simply a helper method provided by Laravel that creates a field with the correct `type` and the required `foreign` key reference. Previously you had to do that all yourself, for example:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

> why you used first()?

The reason for using [`first()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_first) is that it returns a `Model` rather than an [Eloquent Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-collections). You're only interested in one `User` (the authenticated `User`) so it is more efficient to use `first()` rather than `get()` as you don't then need to loop or extract the first item in the collection.

You might want to spend some free time watching the [Laravel from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch) series. It is really detailed and covers lots of common scenarios.

Comment: It really worked. Thanks a lot sir. If you could, can you explain me how it was resolved? I'm a beginner so I want to learn

Comment: @ThantHtetAung Which part(s) of the answer do you want clarification on?

Comment: I kinda grasp the way you solved but still don't know why I should use foreignId? Also why you used first()? I'd like to learn that

Comment: @ThantHtetAung I have updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, In your controller you should load the subs. That will be better as it will not add extra query for loading the relations. So what you can do is following

```
$data = User::with('subs')->all();
```

you should also change the relationship as hasMany follows the following convention:

```
   public function subs(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Subscription');
   }
```

As you are pulling all the users you have to first loop through the users first, then you can iterate over subs for each users like below:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @foreach ($user->subs as $sub)
        <span class="ms-2">{{$subs->name}}</span>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: It shows this error 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()"

Comment: use User::with('subs')->get();

Comment: i got the entire list but i only want current user's subscribers. How can do that? Using Auth?

Comment: Then you have do the following `$data = auth()->user()->with('subs');`

Comment: I don't get any user back to the list. I have logged in as user id 1. and user id 1 has 3 subscribers. How to take out that three subscribers' name?

Comment: what does `auth()->user()` returns?

Comment: It returned current logged in user

Comment: Then if you defined the relationship correctly it should return the related subs. can you try this once `auth()->user()->load('subs');`

Comment: It returns a lot of subscribers but still not related subs.